# I need to check the X & Y points of a CGPoint for an image, then show an alert

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cgpoint

I'm making a game where images fall from the top of the screen, and I need to detect when they reach/go past a certain x & y value. I tried doing:

```
if (asteroid.center.y == 296 && asteroid.center.x == 50) {
    // etc...displayed alert
}
```

But for some reason, it won't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "it won't work", what exactly does it do wrong? Have you tried logging asteroid.center as it reaches the edge of the screen to make sure you're checking for the right values? Is it possible that the asteroid goes from 295 to 297 without ever being at 296?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of object "asteroid" is. If it is an instance of UIView, you should be able to get the position from the UIView's frame property:

```
if (asteroid.frame.origin.y >= 296 && asteroid.frame.origin.x >= 50) {
    // etc...displayed alert
}
```

frame is a CGRect reference. You can learn more about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect

EDIT:

If you wanted to check the center of the asteroid as oppose to the top/left, it would look like this:

```
if (asteroid.frame.origin.y + asteroid.frame.size.height / 2 >= 296 && asteroid.frame.origin.x + asteroid.frame.size.width / 2 >= 50) {
        // etc...displayed alert
}
```

Comment: The only difference between this and the OP is you have used the top left corner of the image instead of the center..